# How to change string to list in pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, string, list, python-re

I have data frame where one column has rows like this:

```
'["user1", "user2" ... ]'
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
["user1", "user2" ... ]
```

I want to do it this way, using strip(), but I do not know how to write " ' " in brancets.

```
df.col =  df.col.str.strip("")
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` function to achieve this. Given a string, `eval` parses it to python expression.

Example:

```
>>> str_items = '["user1", "user2"]'
>>> items = eval(str_items)
>>> type(items)
<class 'list'>
```

From the example we can see that the string expression is converted to python  list.

To apply eval to all items in column of a data frame we can use `apply` function.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame()
>>> frame["items"] = [ '["user1", "user2"]', '["user1", "user2"]']
```

Now I have constructed a data frame similar to yours. Only thing remaining is  that we need to convert all items in frame column to list.

```
>>> frame["items"] = frame["items"].apply(eval)
>>> type(frame['items'][0])
<class 'list'>
```